# Android terminating a thread created through runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, terminate, runnable

Let's say in various points in my application, I create and fire off a new runnable like so:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
    while(true) {
       //do lots of stuff
       //draw lots of stuff on screen, have a good ol time
       //total loop processing time abt 1250-1500ms
       //check for conditions to stop the loop, break;
   }    }   }
```

Now, is there any way to terminate that thread midway through execution other than `break;` inside my while loop?  I'd like to be able to kill it specifically and immediately from the parent thread, like, as in the event that the user just requested to load a different map.  It feels clunky to insert an `if (stopFlag) break;` (set in parent thread) after every 5 or so lines of code.

I peeked at Runnable's and Thread's methods and I just can't see it.  Someone know an awesome trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and call [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) to cancel the thread.

Comment: I'm going to look into reworking my code to make use of this.  I'll let you know how it turns out soon.  This seems more elegant.

Comment: @Eric You never let us know how it turned out! : (

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `while (true)` you may check for a condition or a flag that would be changed properly when the Thread/Runnable should be stopped. This seems to be the [suggested strategy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) since Thread.stop() has been deprecated.

Comment: This is not a good solution because it still blocks on blocking calls - for example if there's a long HTTP download in the while loop.

Comment: So how does the implementation of `AsyncTask` take into account the use case you are talking about?

Comment: I don't think it does. I had to work around it and manually call disconnect() on every HttpURLConnection - that did the trick (but I believe this only works starting from Gingerbread, there is an Android bug thread about it http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11705)

Answer (score 0):

You could use AsyncTask as suggested, which probably works best in this case. I believe you can also use the interrupt() method, which is preferred if good if you're not in Android, but still suffers from having to explicitly check if it is interrupted:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // do some stuff
            if (isInterrupted()) {
                break;
            }
        }
     });
t.start();

// Whoa! Need to stop that work!
t.interrupt();
```

Comment: This is not a good solution because it still blocks on blocking calls - for example if there's a long HTTP download in the while loop.

Comment: The main thread does not block; this creates a new thread and then the long HTTP download occurs on the new thread (because start() is called rather than run()).